# Why do my bath fan's heat and light not work even after replacing the unit and the switch?

Tags: bathroom, switch, heater

The heat and light in our older [Nutone Heat/light/vent](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00084URME) suddenly stopped working (vent still works).

We replaced it with the identical model, but the heat and light still didn't work.

So we replaced the wall switch with an identical switch, but the heat and light still don't work.

Does this mean there's an issue involving the wiring in the house that leads to these devices? And beyond our DIY skills, of course?

Comment: Welcome. Pulling a new cable (should that be the proper solution) isn't beyond your DIY skills. If you can rewire the unit _and_ the switch, you can connect a new cable. It may involve attic access or drywall work, but....

Comment: Please provide some clear photos of the wiring at both ends. If you don't have reason to believe that the cable was damaged somehow, the problem must be there. Do you have rodents in the house?

Answer (score 1):

Not meaning to be rude, but you're just throwing parts at your problem before properly diagnosing the *CAUSE* .   What you should have done is get a multi-meter and test for power to the old unit. If no power to the heat/light portion, you certainly can't expect the unit to operate.

Moving on, if no power, then you check the switch for power, carefully of course. Then check outlets and breaker.  In older homes, built under different codes, sometimes the outlets and lighting where on the same circuit.   If so, it's quite possible a connection in a bathroom outlet failed (probably because of the notorious back-stab connections) and cut power to one of the switches.

All you can do is trace the problem back as far as possible...being careful around live circuits.

Lastly, you might have to get into the breaker panel (ONLY IF YOU ARE COMFORTABLE WITH THAT), turn off the breaker for the affected circuit and check for continuity with an OHM  meter.

But, and as much as I hate to say this, based on your post and what you tried, it might be time to call in a pro.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently there is a problem with the power supply to the light and heat part of the device. Whether that problem is within your skills or not is your call - plenty of folks DIY wiring, plenty of others don't. I'd pull out a meter (not a "non-contact-tester," I don't own one and from everything I know I don't want one) and check voltages on cables. If you'd prefer to call an electrician at that point, that's your call.

Answer (score 0):

Page 16 of the manual for this product shows a diagram. Item 19 is a "Thermal Protector" which is commonly called a thermal fuse. This is a component that permanently cuts power to the protected device if the device becomes too hot. It does not reset automatically when it cools off; a thermal fuse that has blown must be replaced.

If dust has built up in the heater or if air flow is otherwise restricted, then the air flow through the device will be insufficient to remove heat, its temperature may rise, and the thermal fuse may blow to prevent a fire. The light may be wired internally to the same thermal fuse, since high-wattage lights also produce heat and thermal protection is prudent, and required in some jurisdictions.

If the power is on and your power switch is in a position that should produce heat and light, and you read full line voltage across the two terminals of the thermal fuse, the fuse has blown. If you read no voltage across the two terminals, it has not blown. If you don't have the equipment and experience to do this test safely, you might consider hiring a handyman or an electrician to test the thermal fuse and/or further diagnose the problem.

Comment: Does not cover why the brand new replacement doesn't work, and that makes it less likely that this is the issue with the original device, as well.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Dang, I missed that line. You're right, of course!